# Conformal map from $\Omega = \{z \in \mathbb{C} | \operatorname{Re}(z)>0\} \setminus [0,1]$ to unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

> Find a conformal map $f$ from $\Omega = ${$z \in \mathbb{C} | \operatorname{Re}(z)>0$}$ \setminus [0,1]$ to unit disk $\mathbb{D}$. Also make sure that $f(2) = 0$.

I drew $\Omega$ (see image below, $\Omega$ is the sketched part without the blue line) and from this I want to use a composition of conformal maps to get a conformal map that maps $\Omega$ to the unit disk.

[image: Drawing of Omega]

The problem is that I don't know how I can manipulate the split or get rid of it. I know that I can use
$$ z \mapsto \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$$
and choose 3 points that I want to map to other points, but also for this I don't know which ones I would use.

Can somebody help me with an idea of how I should get rid of the split? Or is there a common method for conformal maps for domains with splits?

Comment: If you apply the square $z \mapsto z^2$ to your region, you get a perhaps simpler region to do.

Comment: This is m attempt: first $z \mapsto iz$ so that everything rotates and I have the upperhalf plane with split $[0,1]$ on the imaginary axis. Then $z \mapsto z^2$ which gives the $\mathbb{C} \setminus [-1, \infty)$. Then $z \mapsto -(z +1)$ to get $\mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty, 0]$. Then $z \mapsto z^{1/2}$ to get the right plane, then $z \mapsto iz$  to get the upperhalf plane. On this I can apply $z \mapsto \frac{i-z}{i+z}$ to get the unit circle. Is this a correct idea? All I have to do then is check if $f(2) = 0$, or maybe add a map to the half plane before the map to the unit circle.

Comment: The idea is correct. If you end up with $f(2)\neq0$, just add an automorphism of the disc which swaps $f(2)$ with $0$.

Comment: I was thinking of doing the map before getting the circle. How would I add an automorphism of the disc swapping $f(2)$ with 0. How do I define the automorphism?

Comment: Oh I see now, automorphisms was a part of the theory that I hadn't seen yet but reading further in the book I came across. Thank you all for the help!